# Trying to have a window where the row of sevens are visible and rest is hidden - images are spritesheet.png in div tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to have a window where the row of sevens are visible and the rest of them arent for my website as it for a slot machine and i want the rest is hidden - images are spritesheet.png in div tags. Any ideas? 
here is a image of my website with containers - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRayb.jpg) 
Thanks for the help 
and here is my tags i used.

```
<div class="outerbox">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/spritesheet.png">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/spritesheet.png">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/spritesheet.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So in short only images named specifically, like 'spritesheet.png' should be visible and other names should be hidden, right?